# Stuck in login loop in Ubuntu 16.04 after installing NVIDIA

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, login

I recently updated my Linux kernel in Ubuntu 16.04 to `4.20.6` because of wifi issue. Now whenever I try installing NVIDIA drivers and reboot, I get stuck in login loop. Here is what **Additional Drivers** is showing

[image]

I tried many things mentioned in forum but none of them seems to work. The graphics card details is

> 1f:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] [10de:128b] (rev a1)

I tried solutions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics), but it doesn't seem to work. My secure boot is disabled too.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
This is what I am getting during installation

```
Loading new nvidia-410-410.78 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.20.6
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
```

and this is what I am getting during purge

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/acr/unload_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
```

**EDIT 1**

This problem is due to upgradation of Kernel to **4.20**. It works fine with default Kernel. ANY HELP will be appreciated!!

Comment: My first suggestion is purge the Nvidia drivers, **remove the PPA**, and then install the recommended Nvidia drivers version from the official repositories. You don't need the brand new versions for a GT710.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia already purged and removed PPA many times. what should be the recommended version?

Comment: The Nvidia website suggests 410 only and that version is - I think - available at the official repositories for 16.04. So, start by *not* adding the graphics drivers PPA *and* purging all the drivers installed before with `sudo apt purge nvidia*`.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia same is happening

Comment: Did you check the login-loop fix in https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop ?

Comment: @ubfan1 yes already. from there only I got to know this is NVIDIA driver problem.